# Massive production of antimatter in industry

Tags: antimatter

Would the massive (industrial) production of antimatter be possible?

I am speaking of tons of antimatter, not only nanograms.

I am speaking of an industrial process similar to the production of massive pills or chemical compounds for human use.

Comment: And how would you safely store these tons of antimatter? 1 gram of antimatter together with 1 gram of matter would already release the energy of an atomic bomb.

Comment: It's not prohibited by the laws of physics. But unless you have a practical way to harness the energy from matter + antimatter annihilation what's the point of storing energy as antimatter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The earth's energy consumption of about $20~\rm PWh$, if somehow put solely into pair production of antimatter and matter with perfect efficiency, would produce not even half a ton of antimatter in a year. With more realistic efficiencies, the quantity is much, much less.

Comment: Great answer! Also(just to add to your answer), as far as I know there is no physical process in which we can use anti-matter in our daily lives. The problem is that it annihilates instantly so there is no prospect of chemical bonds with matter. Producing massive amounts of anti-matter, at least currently, is really insightful in exploring the properties of anti-matter.

Comment: 20 kWh seems a *tad* low

Comment: @simplicio Remember 20kWh is a power unit, meaning it's energy per **hour**

Comment: Where did you find the $20~\rm kWh$ ?
[Wikipedia - World energy consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_energy_consumption#Electricity_generation)
says it is around $19500~\rm TWh$.

Comment: @fielder  Kilowatt is a power unit.  kWh is an energy unit.  20 kwh is about what one household consumes in 2 days.  I assume Chris meant 20Twh

Comment: @simplicio Oh god, you are **right**! Sorry, I had the units confused my self. Surely it is a **lot** more than 20kWh.

Comment: Uh, yeah. It's more than a bit low. One downside of SI units is one letter typos can be pretty bad. ;)

Comment: @fielder while going to a hospital for a PET scan - e.g. to look for certain cancers - might not be something we would think of as "in our daily lives", nonetheless there are dozens of these being performed each day in my city alone, using antimatter production as an essential component: *positron-emission tomography*.

Comment: For safety, you wouldn't want to manufacture or on Earth but in orbit. So space based solar comes into play, and with enough solar you could exceed the 20PWh, no?

Comment: @RossPresser if we're being realistic, no. One of those big solar panels people put on top of their house produces about $500~\rm kWh$ per year. That means we would need to put 40 billion of those into space to reach $20~\rm PWh$ per year. As each one weighs around 20 kilograms, that's 800 million metric tons of solar panel. No launch vehicle has ever achieved a cost of less than \$1k/kg, meaning it would cost more than \$800 trillion just to lift all these panels into space, ignoring even the cost of the panels. That's much more than the GDP of the whole planet.

Comment: @chris 500 kWh/yr is at least a factor of four too low for space solar -- no night, no clouds, no atmospheric dispersion -- but I suppose not as much as an order of magnitude, so I guess I'll accept what you've written.

Comment: @RossPresser That did occur to me shortly after I posted the comment, but so do some factors that push the estimate in the opposite direction. (Notably that our usual method of creating antimatter is "large, very heavy particle accelerator"). So I just called it a wash.